# enforce column encoding with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to create the schema of my database. I have no success in enforcing the use of utf-8, no matter what I tried.

Here is a minimal python script that recreates my problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:password@localhost/multidic?charset=utf8', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
class MyTableName(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytablename"
    test_column = Column(Unicode(2),primary_key=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

After running this script, when I look into the database, I see that the encoding is latin1 instead of utf-8:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM mytablename;
+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field       | Type       | Collation         | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| test_column | varchar(2) | latin1_swedish_ci | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried changing the type of the column created (**String** instead of **Unicode**), and tried also to add the argument **encoding = "utf8"** in the call to **create_engine**, but none of it worked.

So, my question is:

*How to enforce the use of a given character encoding (utf-8 in my case) in MySQL, with sqlalchemy ?*

Thank you :)

### Notes:

I am using sqlalchemy 0.7 and python 2.7; I can possibly upgrade one or both, but only if it is the only solution!

I have mysql 5, and it supports utf-8:

```
mysql> show character set where charset="utf8";
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description   | Default collation | Maxlen |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| utf8    | UTF-8 Unicode | utf8_general_ci   |      3 |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i remember last time i used MySql i ended up declaring utf-8 in like *four* places, like in the global conf, in the table def, on the connection object, and when doing the query.—that said, i see little reason to use MySql at all (**THESE ID*TS USE LATIN-1 WITH SWEDISH COLLATION AS DEFAULT**). if i want a SQL db then i take Postgresql, which is free, well document, reasonably designed, and fast.—not ten horses could pull me back onto the ORM/SqlAlchemy bandwagon; it feels MUCH too complicated for what it does, and queries formulated SqlA-style are *not a bit* more readable than literal SQL.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To specify a specific collation per column, use the [`collation`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.NVARCHAR) parameter on the data type:

```
class MyTableName(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytablename2"
    test_column = Column(Unicode(2),
                         primary_key=True)
    test_column2 = Column(Unicode(2, collation='utf8_bin'))
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Mind that MySQL understands this as both the set of codepoints to describe the text as well as the sort order the text will be indexed with; the usual suspects like 'utf8' or 'utf-8' won't be familiar to MySQL (use `SHOW COLLATION` to see the full list)

```
mysql> show full columns from mytablename2;
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field        | Type       | Collation         | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| test_column  | varchar(2) | latin1_swedish_ci | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| test_column2 | varchar(2) | utf8_bin          | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Trying `test_column2 = Column(Unicode(2, collation='utf8_bin'))` throws an error:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'collation'` ...

In addition, trying `test_column2 = Column(Unicode(2), collation='utf8_bin')` throws another error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Unknown arguments passed to Column: ['collation']`

Comment: exactly what the world needs—A DATABASE THAT CONFUSES ENCODING WITH COLLATION, AND CALLS ENCODING 'CHARSET'. did you know Latin-1 is seriously OUTDATED ever since it got replaced by Latin-9 = ISO-8859-15 **in 1999**? Latin-1 doesn't even have a Euro-sign.

Comment: **Upgrading to the latest version of SQLalchemy (i.e. 0.8.2) made your solution work**...

Thank you !!

Answer (score 5):

For me the collation parameter did not work.

My connection string was:

`db = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@dbhost/schema?charset=utf8')`

Pymysql was executing set names utf8 because of the charset, and the database was converting the utf8 to the encoding of the table, resulting in data loss.

If i left the charset out, the charset was defaulting to latin1, and pymysql was trying to encode my utf8 strings to latin1 before sending them to the database, thus throwing UnicodeEncode errors.

This worked for me :`session.execute(text("SET NAMES latin1"))`
to make the database assume the utf8 strings i was sending did not need to be converted.